# Restrict Android App Login to Paying Google User

Tags: android, authentication, google-play, authorization

Can a paid Android app know the user id who paid for it?  Actually I am not even sure whether the app author can know the user identification of those who paid for it -- so I would appreciate knowing that too.

If the app cannot know the user id, but the author can, then can the app read the Google account under which the Android phone is signed in?  And thereby provide services only if it is the user that paid for it?

I am not trying to restrict the use of the app itself if pirated (it does little on its own), but I want to restrict access to the web service solely to those who paid for it.

Answer (score 1):

you can get the userId detail when the user logs in.
Just compare it with the table of paid users, and grant the access.

Comment: +1 thanks. I assume that means the answer is yes, the app author can get the list of paid user ids from Google Play. And then I ask the user to sign in with Google as the paying user id.